# Tweepy v2 works however returns a error in console

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

I am building a Twitter bot using Tweepy v2 and it works as the bot sends the tweet out however an error returned in the console and the bot stops. I am unable to understand what the error is and would deeply appreciate some help here.

```
import tweepy


def getClient():
  client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token=beare_token, consumer_key=consumer_key,consumer_secret=consumer_secret,access_token=access_token,access_token_secret=access_token_secret)

  return client

def main():
  client = getClient()
  tweet = 'This is a test tweet.'

  response = client.create_tweet(text=tweet)
  print(response)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Below is the error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 38, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 34, in main
    response = client.create_tweet(text=tweet)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tweepy/client.py", line 523, in create_tweet
    return self._make_request(
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tweepy/client.py", line 166, in _make_request
    response = self.request(method, route, params=request_params,
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tweepy/client.py", line 108, in request
    with self.session.request(
AttributeError: __enter__
```

Comment: Which version of Tweepy are you using?

Comment: I am using 4.4.0

Comment: So try to update to the latest version (currently 4.10.1) first. On a side note, please note that, accordingly to the Python coding style, the name of the functions should be lowercase with an underscore between the words ([see here](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names)).

Comment: It still did not work and I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error and these steps fixed it for me:

1. Sign in to Developer Portal.
2. Open the page of your Development.
3. Select the tab of Keys and tokens.
4. Regenerate Access Token and Secret.